# Background color & height of div / stretch div

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrapper and not very good with the css styles. I need the grey bar to stretch the whole way down the left as on home page. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong http://www.webconstruct.co.za/wis/terms.asp Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not an easy thing to do with just CSS. I'd solve the problem with jQuery.

```
$(function(){
    $('#leftcolmn').height($('#rightcolmn').height());
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('#leftcolmn').height($('#rightcolmn').height());
    });
});
```

This solution would work much better if you had some classes or IDs on the two columns that you want to modify and get values from.

The code:

```
$(function(){

});
```

Functions exactly the same as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

Comment: $(function(){
    $('leftcolmn').height($('rightcolmn').height());
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('leftcolmn').height($('rightcolmn').height());
    });
});

I added id's to both divs.. do I need the document.getElementById... & how do I call onload?

Comment: I updated my answer. I used a jQuery shorthand method to call on document ready.

Comment: Ok feeling stupid now.. I added 2 id's for the 2 divs..
So would this be correct? How do I call the function?

$(function(){
    $('.leftcolmn1').height($('.rightcolmn1').height());
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('.leftcolmn1').height($('.rightcolmn1').height());
    });
});

Comment: Put it inside $(document).ready(function(){//code goes here});

Comment: Thanks for your help Tom.
Updated the jquery, changed code but no joy..
$(document).ready(function(){$(function(){
    $('.leftcolmn1').height($('.rightcolmn1').height());
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('.leftcolmn1').height($('.rightcolmn1').height());
    });
});});
Can you check my page?

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hi Tom
Not sure if you saw my thank you message? Ur a Legend! I did but have to adjust the function so that the height returns to normal when the navbar has collapsed.. I will post what I have tomorrow am..

Comment: I have the function running, first I set the value of a text box the original length, and the left column is stretching, if the nav has toggled I then try to set the height back to the value of the text field but not sure where to set the listner to?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 vcolheight = $("#leftcolmn1").height()
 document.getElementById('sidenavHeight').value = vcolheight;
 
 $(function(){
  $('#leftcolmn1').height($('#rightcolmn1').height());
   $(window).resize(function(){
    $('#leftcolmn1').height($('#rightcolmn1').height());
    $('#leftcolmn1').height($('#rightcolmn1').height());
  });
  
  if($('.navbar-header').on)
  {
   alert();
   $(window).resize(function(){
    $('#leftcolmn1').height($('#sidenavHeight').value());
    $('#leftcolmn1').height($('#sidenavHeight').value());
   });
  }
 });
});

Answer (score 0):

use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (available in Bootstrap 4 alpha) - there is an example of similar layout at the end of article (which is not made by Bootstrap, but could be customized like this)

more here: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/flexbox-grid/

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick but you have to test it for all the pages.

    `.col-sm-3 {
        margin-bottom: -255%;
        padding-bottom: 255%;
    }`